# How can I refresh every activity when using TabLayout Android?

Tags: android, refresh, android-tabhost

I'd already ask about this, but still don't have an answer.
I think the   [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950399/how-can-i-logout-from-my-application-and-refresh-on-android) is not clearly delivered the question correctly.
It is right, they can resolve my first problem, but not the second one.

And the second problem is when I try to come into my TabActivity that include three tab, then I can't refresh it one by one on every activity. My refresh button on my menu that I'd already created is just refresh it but bring me into the first tab, not the current active tab.

Does anyone can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: cant get you ....explain properly....!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer, but a possible clarification of Aditya's question.

Aditya has an app with three TabActivities. When a user changes something in the contents of the first tab, it should cause a change in the contents of the other two tabs. The change should show up immediately when one of the other tabs is selected - that is, when one of the other tabs is selected, Aditya wants the contents to be updated before they are displayed.

One (clumsy) workaround is to include a manual Refresh button in every tab's layout. That works, but it would be better not to require the user to refresh the view manually.

In addition, Aditya's implementation of the Refresh button has a bug, in that it refreshes all three tabs, but then always changes to display the first tab. Aditya wants the refresh to always show the current (refreshed, of course) tab.

Ideally, the Refresh button would not be needed at all, since simply selecting a new tab would update the layout before displaying it.

If I have misspoken, I apologize. But that's how I read it.